# I get error when trying to allocate 2D array, then use them

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate a `2D array` in a `function`, but when I use this function my whole SDL apps crashes. If I comment out just the line where I call the function, there is no problem.

The return I get: `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

My Structs:

```
typedef struct Game
{
    int x;
    int y;
    GameMode mode;
    Field field;
} Game;

typedef struct Cell
{
    CellType type;
    bool shown;
    bool marked;
} Cell;
```

This is how I initialize the `Game` and set a pointer of pointer for `Cell`.

```
Game game;
Cell **cells;
setup_ui(&game, cells);
```

`setup_ui` function: `static int setup_ui(Game *game, Cell **cells)`

In the `setup_ui` I have the function which causes the problem:

```
cells = setup_cells(game, cells);
```

And the function itself:

```
Cell** setup_cells(Game *game, Cell** cells){
    cells = (Cell**) malloc(game->y*sizeof(Cell*));

    for(int x=0; x<game->y; x++){
        cells[x] = (Cell*) malloc(x * sizeof(Cell));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<game->x; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<game->y; j++){
            cells[i][j].type = simple;
            cells[i][j].shown = false;
            cells[i][j].marked = false;
        }
    }
    return cells;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you never actually set `game.x` and `game.y`?

Comment: OT: why do you pass `cells` to the function?

Comment: Why you are passing `cells` (not a pointer to `cells`) while passing a pointer to `game` to `setup_ui()`?

Comment: In `setup_cells` the argument variable `cells` is a ***local*** variable, whose initial value is *copied* from the value used in the call. All modification you do to this variable will be lost when the life-time of the local variable ends when the function returns. Either use what the function *returns*, or *emulate pass by reference*.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't seem to initialize the `Game` structure, which means all its members will have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Notice that `cells` are also the return value

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But `setup_cells` returns `cell`, so the structure looks weird but not critical. The index problem that @Aplet123 points out is critical though.

Comment: Sorry for returning  `cells`. This is the reason of trying to solve the problem. The basic function returned nothing :) And thanks for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's a mistake here:

```c
for(int x=0; x<game->y; x++){
    cells[x] = (Cell*) malloc(x * sizeof(Cell));
}
```

This should be `malloc(game->x * sizeof(Cell))`, since `x` is the current index, but `game->x` is the actual width. However, the error comes from the fact that here:

```c
for(int i=0; i<game->x; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<game->y; j++){
        cells[i][j].type = simple;
        cells[i][j].shown = false;
        cells[i][j].marked = false;
    }
}
```

`i` can go up to `game->x`, and `j` can go up to `game->y`, but the first dimension is of size `game->y` and the second dimension is of size `game->x`. So, you should flip the bounds of `i` and `j`.